# Laravel - multi-table insert with relationships

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have 3 tables that should be populated when creating an order and I would like to know the best way to do this.

**Tables**

```
Orders
- id (pk)
- company_id
- address_id (join to items table)
- date
- source
- ...

Addresses
- id (pk)
- company_id
- name
- email
- address
- ...

Items
- id (pk)
- order_id (join to orders table)
- product_id
- qty
- ...
```

**Relationships**

- Address table belongsTo the orders table
- Order hasMany items
- We have a multi-tennant (single db) structure so the company_id is used to separate data between companies. Both the order and the address belongsTo the company.

**Creation**

My understanding is that the address would need to be created first to get the ID. Then the order would be created, followed by the items.

I would also like to ensure that if any insert fails, no data would be saved (as in a SQL transaction).

I wonder if anyone can point my in the right direction for the best way to do this? So far I have the following

```
$address = OrderAddress::create([
    'company_id' => Auth::user()->company_id,
    'name' => 'test test',
    'email' => 'test@test.com',
    'address' => '78 test street',
]);
$order = $address->order()->create([
    //'address_id' => populated by model
    'company_id' => Auth::user()->company_id,
    'date' => '2018-03-23',
    'source' => 'mystore'
]);
foreach($items as $item){
    OrderItem::create([
        'order_id' => $order->order_id,
        'product_id' => $item->product_id,
        'qty' => $item->qty
    ]);
}
```

My main issues are that:

1. this does not work as a transaction, i.e. a failure will not create a roll back.
2. Im not sure I am using the model relationships to their full potential.

Comment: A transaction should definitely work. How do you use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is basically two improvements you can make. One for each of your issues.

1. To wrap everything in a transaction, you can put the `create` statements in a `DB::transaction(...)` block. For reference, have a look at [the manual](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/database#database-transactions). There is also another way of using transactions described in there.
2. The same relationship `create` method you used when creating your `Order` can also be applied to the `OrderItems`: `$order->items()->create([...])`.

The final code snippet could look something like this:

```
DB::transaction(function () {
    $address = OrderAddress::create([
        'company_id' => Auth::user()->company_id,
        'name' => 'test test',
        'email' => 'test@test.com',
        'address' => '78 test street',
    ]);
    $order = $address->order()->create([
        'company_id' => Auth::user()->company_id, // actually, this information is already available through the `address`
        'date' => '2018-03-23',
        'source' => 'mystore'
    ]);
    foreach($items as $item){
        $order->items()->create([
            'order_id' => $order->order_id,
            'product_id' => $item->product_id,
            'qty' => $item->qty
        ]);
    }
});
```

Please make sure to change the relationship name if it is called `orderItems()` instead of `items()`.

Comment: Thanks for this @Namoshek. Can I extend my question and ask where you would suggest storing this kind of code? I read that keeping controllers thin and models fat is good practice but considering this code runs across multiple controllers, does this still make sense?

Answer (score 1):

DB::transaction(...)

or

DB::beginTransaction();

You can rollback the transaction via the rollBack method:

DB::rollBack();

Lastly, you can commit a transaction via the commit method:

DB::commit();